# In what kind of research should I analyse its possibility, necessity and feasibility?

Tags: thesis, masters, asia

I'm an educational/instructional technology major in China. My supervisor asked me to analyse my thesis' possibility, necessity and feasibility which seldom have I seen in papers written by Western researchers. What's more, I have articulated the literature review ahead. I'm just wondering if masters in your university need to write such things.

#### the background

It may sound strange to you, but I'm truly confused on this issue. I'm pursuing a master degree under a very reputed and elderly tenured professor. Although he has a PHD background in Dutch in the earlier 1980s, I thought he is kind of too non-international.

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you see a difference between "possibility" and "feasability"?

Comment: A study may be possible but not feasible if time or other conditions don't permit. Hoping that we're on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The introduction of articles usually explain why are you doing what you are doing, i.e., the necessity. You don't see feasibility analysis because they are, obviously, possible, since they have been done. On the other hand, grant proposals do it: they have to convince the committee that the research they propose is possible, useful, and can be done on time. You could ask your supervisor for some of his grant proposals as an example. This is not always done because this is in general a difficult analysis to do.

Furthermore, MSc thesis are often used as feasibility analysis on their own: the professor gets someone to work for a few months on a topic, and can (hopefully) discover most of the problems in advance. If the results are promising, it will be offered as a PhD or postdoc project.

By making you do the literature review in advance he is making you get up to date with the field, something that everybody has to do when starting a new research topic. Bear in mind that this section will have to be expanded and rewritten as you advance your research and discover that you need other tools.

Answer (score 1):

In my completed and successful MSc and PhD, as part of the Introduction, in a section named 'Rationale', I included a justification of the possibility and necessity of the research using a literature review of the current status of the research. The literature review also formed as a basis of the feasibility of the methods that would be employed.